# null pointer exception on adding string object to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Cant get around this. Null Pointer exception occurs when trying to add a String object to an ArrayList. Trouble is, I believe I have already initialized the 'temp' ArrayList properly. Please help.

```
void initialConbinations(String[] headers) {
    //Dataset is SN,FN,RN,PN
    //Map the headers to the appropriate portions
    String[] newHeaders = {"SN,high", "SN,medium", "SN,low", "FN,high", "FN,medium", "FN,low", "RN,high", "RN,medium", "RN,low"};
    List<List> assRuleHeaders = new ArrayList<List>();
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Use bitwise shifting to do the rest
    int k = 0, l = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 511; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            l = i;
            k = (l >> j) & 0x00000001;
            if (k == 1) {
                System.out.println(k + " , " + i + " , " + j);
                System.out.println(newHeaders[j]);
                temp.add(newHeaders[j]);    //Getting a Null Pointer Exception here
            }
        }
        assRuleHeaders.add(temp);
        temp = null;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < assRuleHeaders.size(); i++) {
        this.printArray(assRuleHeaders.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of superfluous code in there. Mind cleaning it up a bit to make it easier to see? Also, mind pasting the print stream?

Comment: Sorry about that. Newbie here, will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is with the line

```
temp = null;
```

You are not reinitializing `temp` again.

if you move the line

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
```

between the two for loops all should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

At the last step of `i` loop you are setting `temp` to null instead of setting it to a new array using `new ArrayList<String>();`. This will cause `temp.add(newHeaders[j]);` to through the null pointer exception.

change

```
temp = null;
```

to

```
temp = new ArrayList<String>();
```